# How to run 2 different consoles using Docker on Heroku?

Tags: docker, heroku, rasa

I have a rasa chatbot app which's deployed on Heroku. I want to run 2 commands in different consoles to start rasa and it's actions.
Here is my docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENTRYPOINT []
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip && python3 -m pip install --no-cache --upgrade pip && pip3 install --no-cache rasa==1.5.3
ADD . /app/
RUN chmod +x /app/start_services1.sh
CMD /app/start_services1.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/start_services2.sh
CMD /app/start_services2.sh
```

start_services1.sh file:

```
cd app/
rasa run actions "*" --debug -p $PORT
```

start_services2.sh file:

```
cd app/
rasa run --model models --enable-api --cors "*" --debug -p $PORT
```

It only runs the second .sh file. The rasa chatbot run without actions.
How can I solve it?

Comment: A container only runs one process.  If you need to do two distinct things, running them in two separate containers is generally a best practice.

Comment: is this works for you? actually, I am facing the same issue. @Phuc Nguyen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats not possible as Heroku exposes only one port per process. The solution is to deploy 2 apps: rasa core and the rasa action server.
Configure `heroku-endpoints.yml` to use the Rasa SDK on Heroku, ie

```
action_endpoint:
  url: "https://{heroku-app}.herokuapp.com/webhook"
```

I have implemented a similar solution already (actually deployed 3 apps as I also needed my own REST service), feel free to have a look https://github.com/perosa/AvatarRasaChatbot

Comment: According to the document you provided, I just need to create rasa-avatarbot and rasasdk-avatarbot. Right? ^^